# Adding a XsltListViewWebPart to a custom web part page causes an issue

Tags: web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

Currently we are developing a custom page with many of the for-mentioned web parts added via the module file related to the `default.aspx` page. Nothing major special seems to work nicely.

However these web parts need to reference a specific view against their representative list. Which is a little bit of a pain because the lists are created as list instances so I do not have the `baseviewID` property until the lists are created in the site.

The resolution I thought would be to add the web part programmatically, It works up to a point.

I can set the chrome type and the view perfectly, However when I throw the `xsllink`, it sets the link and the xslt is applied, however when I try to use the ribbon or any javascript related functionality that is on the page nothing happens.

I an getting an error saying

> Expected '(' at line...

I've not added any js to the page which is why I'm baffled and the error only occurs after adding the xslt link to the web part.

Anyone else experienced this?